Проблемы с aiogram 3
У меня есть такая функция, которая отслеживает кнопку, после её нажатия должны включаться или выключаться субтитры в YouTube. Когда стоит английская раскладка, код работает как надо, но с русской раскладкой у меня вместо субтитров выключается звук. Если запустить код и поменять язык на английский ничего не изменится
@dp.callback_query(F.data == 'btn_sub_ru')
async def sub_ru(call: CallbackQuery):
    if not is_authorized(call.message):
        await call.message.reply("Доступ запрещён!")
        return
    try:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.send("c")
        await call.message.reply("Субтитры переключены.")
    except Exception as e:
        error = await call.message.reply(f"Ошибка: {str(e)}")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await error.delete()


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.
